# Sitefinity: How to turn on/off sf-trckngckie cookie?

Tags: cookies, sitefinity

I want to handle turning on/off sf-trckngckie cookie when the user switches the option accept/reject the sf-trckngckie cookie on UI.

https://community.progress.com/s/article/how-to-turn-off-sf-trckngckie-cookie

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: what's your version of sitefinity?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev Sitefinity CMS 12.2

Comment: unfortunately it's not that simple to do it per user, because you may have users who are not authenticated and the best you can do in this case is save their preference in the Session and based on that - you execute the code that is in the KB. But when a new session is created - these settings will be forgotten. So you may need to save their preference in the localstorage as well.

Comment: thanks @VeselinVasilev, all users of my application are anonymous(no authentication), I will keep selected option (about on/off sf-trckngckie) into cookie storage(on the browser). My question about how to enable the sf-trckngckie cookie on UI (use javascript)? (by default I will turn off this cookie following the guide on this https://community.progress.com/s/article/how-to-turn-off-sf-trckngckie-cookie). How to generate value of this cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the code of the Telerik.Sitefinity.Clients.JS.StatsClient.debug.js  file with JustDecompile (Telerik.Sitefinity.dll) OR just inspect the javascript requests from a page and you will find it in one of the WebResource.axd requests.

This is what the LogVisit method looks like (which creates the cookie)

```
LogVisit: function (pageNodeId, randomId) {
        var that = this;
        var logVisit = function (pageNodeId, randomId) {
            if (!that._canTrack) return;

            var trackingCookieName = "sf-trckngckie"

            var trackingId = that.readCookie(trackingCookieName);
            if (!trackingId) {
                trackingId = randomId;
                that.createCookie(trackingCookieName, trackingId, 180);
            }

            // ... some code omitted

        if (window.personalizationManager) {
            window.personalizationManager.addPersonalizedContentLoaded(function () {
                logVisit(pageNodeId, randomId);
            });
        } else {
            logVisit(pageNodeId, randomId);
        }
    }
```

And the randomId parameter is really a Guid.NewGuid() assigned from the server.

Comment: Hi  @Veselin Vasilev, How to i get pageNodeId on UI to excute the code: 
xmlHttp.open("GET", that.getServiceUrl() + "?pageNodeId=" + pageNodeId + "&trackingId=" + trackingId + "&referrer=" + referrer + "&pageUrl=" + window.location.href);

Comment: It uses currentNode.Id where PageSiteNode currentNode = SiteMapBase.GetCurrentNode();

Comment: So, to get pageNodeId by javasscript code to handle, we need to pass the currentNode id to UI, is that right? (we can't get it from window.pageNodeId  or  something like that)

Comment: you can do something like this in your mvc view: <script>var currentPageNodeId = '@SiteMapBase.GetCurrentNode().Id';</script> and then use that variable

Comment: Hi @Veselin, I saw the sf-trackngkie does not appear in Sitefinity version 14.3, is that right?
If yes, could you have any documents for that?

Comment: @ParkJang do you have the Personalization module activated?

Comment: yes, I enable it but I have checked the script for PersonalizationTracker. It only has 4 cookies:  PersonalizationTracker._createCookie("sf-prs-ss", "", -1);
                PersonalizationTracker._createCookie("sf-prs-lu", "", -1);
                PersonalizationTracker._createCookie("sf-prs-vp", "", -1);
                PersonalizationTracker._createCookie("sf-prs-vu", "", -1);